# Poor Speaker Quality on Ubuntu 22.04 (Dell XPS 15) Compared to Windows 11

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, dell, alsa

I recently made the leap to Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell XPS 15 and have been enjoying the experience so far. However, I've encountered a rather frustrating issue regarding the sound quality of the built-in laptop speakers. On Windows 11, the audio output sounds crisp and clear, but on Ubuntu 22.04, it's notably worse.

I've tried various solutions, including tinkering with settings, updates, and even trying different audio drivers, but the quality remains far from satisfactory. I even experimented with loading a suggested preset from **Pulseffects**, which yielded an improvement, but it's still nowhere near the audio quality I'm getting on Windows 11.

I'm reaching out to the community to see if anyone has encountered a similar problem and if there's a viable solution out there that I might have missed. I genuinely want to make the most out of my speakers on Ubuntu, without feeling like I'm missing out on audio quality.

Thank you in advance for your help, and I'm looking forward to your suggestions and advice!

Comment: I have the same issue, really appreciate if someone could help. Officially the Laptop is not yet supported Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I still haven't found any solution. This is extremely weird as Ubuntu officially supports XPS 13 Plus, but none of the regular XPS models support it.

I also tried Ubuntu 23.10 on a bootable USB, still bad quality from the laptop speakers.